# How to specify the result type for F# function's signature?

Tags: f#

I am still somewhat new to F#, I see myself struggling with some function signatures when the compiler fails to infer the type properly. In the Following example the compiler believed that the function type for `TryParse`was `string -> string` so I had to create this definition with the lambda on the right side.

```
type SocialAccount =
    | FacebookAccount
    | UnknownAccount
type SocialAccount with
    static member TryParse:(string -> SocialAccount option) = fun s ->
        match s with
        | "FACEBOOK" -> Some FacebookAccount
        | _ -> None
```

I find that lambda after the equal a little bit ugly and decoupling the arg names from the types makes it a bit unreadable I think. Also create a type for every single complex function makes crowded namespaces.

Isn't there really anyway to define a function and specify its return type? I am looking for something like the following code (which is incorrect):

```
static member TryParse:(s:string -> SocialAccount option) =
  match s with
    | "FACEBOOK" -> Some FacebookAccount
    | _ -> None
```

All suggestions are welcome. Including creative ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a type annotation for the return value at the end of the declaration line:

```
static member TryParse(s: string): SocialAccount option =
```

As an aside, `static member X = fun ... ->` is not equivalent to `static member X(...) =`. The former creates a property, rather than a method.

Comment: thanks for the feedback... I look several times in google and in the documentation and I could not find it anywhere, but somehow it still looked like smelly syntax... also thanks for pointing out the difference between property and method, which explains me why I had some strange behave extending datatypes, haha.